# How does Google Chrome determine a safe and unsafe website?

Tags: security, google-chrome

Google chrome has a way of determining safe and unsafe websites. When it does find an unsafe one, it says that your connection isn't private and that attackers could be on the same website. However, Chrome makes a few mistakes on the security of websites and thinking that there's some phishing going on even though the website is for something like finding a job (this was in my case). So my question is, how does google chrome determine a safe and unsafe website?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it dies a lookup against a database curated by Google ("Safe Browsing"). Its possible that the site is legitimate but has been compromised and is/was injecting malware or similar for some pages and/or some users.

See https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/security/malware for what Google looks for and https://safebrowsing.google.com/ goes into more details of the database Google maintain.